# Test if value of button is true. Android project

Tags: android

I'm programming calculator and I am currently almost done; programing the equals button. I want to be able to test if the equals button was clicked and another button was clicked before that, execute some code this is all I have:

```
package rechee.cool;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    double counter1=0;
    double counter2=0;
    String theOperator;
    //Just have two buttons so far, I'm going to have like 10 more

    public EditText display;        

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Associate the button variable with the xml reference

        display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);}

        //When button is clicked, display the text. How do I do this for the rest of my variables?

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.bOne:
                display.append("1");
                    break;
                case R.id.bTwo:                     
                    display.append("2");
                    break;
                case R.id.bThree:
                    display.append("3");
                    break;
                case R.id.bFour:
                    display.append("4");
                    break;
                case R.id.bFive:
                    display.append("5");
                    break;
                case R.id.bSix:
                    display.append("6");
                    break;

                case R.id.bSeven:
                    display.append("7");
                    break;
                case R.id.bEight:
                    display.append("8");
                    break;
                case R.id.bNine:
                    display.append("9");
                    break;
                case R.id.bZero:
                    display.append("0");
                    break;
                case R.id.bPoint:
                    display.append(".");
                    break;
                case R.id.bClear:
                    display.setText("");
                    break;
                case R.id.bAdd:
                    // to get string of EditText 
                    String display1= display.getText().toString();
                    double displayValue= Double.parseDouble(display1);
                    //to test if display1 is double
                    counter1+= displayValue;
                    String theOperator = "+";
                    break;
                case R.id.bEqual:
                    if (R.id.bAdd=true){

                    }           
            }                       
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just check the operator String  where you put the Operator "+" ?

Comment: You should take a class variable which will store which operator (+, -, *, /) has been clicked. And when user clicked on = button you just need to check that variable which will tell you that which operator was clicked.  Here are some example projects may help you  http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/android-tutorial-part-calculator-app-application-example/ and http://www.androiddom.com/2011/04/creating-android-calculator-tutorial.html

Comment: I still don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack data structure to store every button that is pressed.
When you detect a valid sequence (i.e. operand operator operand equal, 1 + 1 =) execute it and remove the values from the stack.